# Get particular data(SQL script for creating table) from string in JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, postgresql

I'm writing migration script from PostgreSQL to Oracle.
I wanna retrieve `CREATE TABLE` script without any other data.

It should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE public.actor (
    actor_id integer DEFAULT nextval('public.actor_actor_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
    first_name character varying(45) NOT NULL,
    last_name character varying(45) NOT NULL,
    last_update timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL
);
```

But when i'm getting data by using:

`let script = execSync('pg_dump -t \'actor\' --schema-only dvdrental', {encoding: 'utf-8'});`

I receive the data that look like this:

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 13.1
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 13.1

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_table_access_method = heap;

--
-- Name: actor; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

CREATE TABLE public.actor (
    actor_id integer DEFAULT nextval('public.actor_actor_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
    first_name character varying(45) NOT NULL,
    last_name character varying(45) NOT NULL,
    last_update timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL
);


ALTER TABLE public.actor OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- Name: actor actor_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.actor
    ADD CONSTRAINT actor_pkey PRIMARY KEY (actor_id);


--
-- Name: actor last_updated; Type: TRIGGER; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

CREATE TRIGGER last_updated BEFORE UPDATE ON public.actor FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION public.last_updated();


--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

Can you advice me how to get particular string by using `split` method or maybe some `regexp`.
Or maybe some command for getting script from database for `CREATE TABLE` to the `);` range.

Comment: If the input is always formatted like this, you can simply extract everything between `create table` and the `);` line. Otherwise, try using a parser library (search for "javascript sql parser").

Comment: @georg that's what i'm trying to do. I know that i have to extract this particular string, but i don't understand how to do it, when i'm trying to split string it does not work at all, i need pattern for splitting that string.

Comment: see below vvvvvvv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the format is always like this (e.g. it's always pgdump) you can iterate the text line by line and extract everything between `CREATE TABLE` and the closing paren:

```
function *createTableStatements(sql) {
    let buf;

    for (let line of sql.split('\n')) {
        if (line.trim().startsWith('CREATE TABLE'))
            buf = [line]
        else if (buf) {
            buf.push(line);
            if (line.startsWith(');')) {
                yield buf.join('\n');
                buf = null;
            }
        }
    }
}

//

sql = ....

for (let stmt of createTableStatements(sql)) {
   // do something with stmt
}
```

To parse arbitrarily formatted SQL you need a specialized parser library, don't try it with string functions or regular expressions.

Comment: This one helped me, thank you very much for your time and effort ^_^ :)